# Create Border Radius Upisde Down

Tags: html, css

i don't know how to make this type of corner?

i want to create corner like this:-[Image Of Border Radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gViB.png)
i wan to add it into the footer

Comment: Are you trying to make the white div or the red div?

Comment: i want make red div

Answer (score 0):

You could put the red and white backgrounds on in before and after pseudo elements.

If you give them z-index: -1 as in this snippet they will sit behind the actual element.

This snippet puts the red onto the before element, making that the same size as the actual element, and puts the white onto the after element, making it <whatever size you want, probably a % of the whole height> and with rounded bottom corners.

Note that the pseudo elements are positioned absolute so they don't affect the layout of other elements, and they are put top and left of the actual element (which has had position relative set).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mydiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
  /* for demo */
  position: relative;
}

.mydiv::after,
.mydiv::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.mydiv::before {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.mydiv::after {
  height: 20%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```